# Sumar columna total con django-filter y paginado (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Es posible sumar las columnas de totales desde django para que por ejemplo me traiga el total de todas las ventas pero que ignore la paginación al momento de sumar los valores.

**Este es mi modelo:**

```
class Venta(models.Model):
    cliente = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Cliente')
    fecha =  models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, verbose_name='Detalle del pedido')
    total = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, verbose_name='Total de la venta')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)
```

Los filtros que hice con la librería **django-filter**

```
class VentasFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    min_date = django_filters.DateFilter(name="fecha", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_date = django_filters.DateFilter(name="fecha", lookup_expr='lte')
    min_total = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="total", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_total = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="total", lookup_expr='lte')
    class Meta:
        model = Venta
        fields = ['cliente','min_date', 'max_date','min_total','max_total']
```

Y aquí la vista de la lista de ventas:

```
def filterVenta(request):
    venta_list = Venta.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    venta_filter = VentasFilter(request.GET, queryset=venta_list)
    venta_list = venta_filter.qs
    paginator = Paginator(venta_list,10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        ventas = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        ventas = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        ventas = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'venta/venta_filter.html', {'filter': venta_filter,'ventas': ventas})
```

Con el cuál no tengo ningun problema pero quisiera sumar todos los totales  pero que no reconozca la **paginación** o sea si hay 100 ventas que me traiga el total de las **100** ventas y no solo el total de las 10 que hay en la paginación y de igual manera cuando hay un filtro que me traiga el total de todas esas ventas del filtro.

Anteriormente cuando no tenía paginación lo hacia desde el cliente con jquery pero ahora que tengo paginación necesito hacer la suma desde el backend(django).

Aquí mi template donde hice la suma pero con jquery por si a alguien le sirve:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block titulo %}Filtros de ventas{% endblock %}
{% block contenido %}
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'venta:venta_crear' %}">Registrar venta</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Ventas</li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
   <form method="get">
    <div class="spaceFilter">
    <div class="card border-info">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="font-weight-bold">Filtros de ventas:</h5>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <label for="cliente"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Cliente: </label>
            {% render_field filter.form.cliente class="form-control" %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <label for="desdeDate"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Desde: </label>
            {% render_field filter.form.min_date class="form-control" %}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group  col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <label for="hastaDate"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Hasta: </label>
            {% render_field filter.form.max_date class="form-control" %}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <label for="desdeMonto"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> Monto desde: </label>
            {% render_field filter.form.min_total class="form-control" %}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <label for="hastaMonto"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> Monto hasta: </label>
            {% render_field filter.form.max_total class="form-control" %}
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-md">
        <span><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></span> Filtrar
      </button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="table-responsive-md">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="tabla-today">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Fecha de venta</th>
          <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
          <th scope="col">Descripción del pedido</th>
          <th scope="col">Total de la venta</th>
          <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for venta in ventas %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ venta.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ venta.fecha}}</td>
        <td>{{ venta.cliente }}</td>
        <td>{{ venta.descripcion }}</td>
        <td><span class="total-list">{{ venta.total }}</span></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'venta:venta_editar' venta.id %}"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg spaceIcon" style="color:#007bff"></i></a>
      <a href="{% url 'venta:venta_eliminar' venta.id %}"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg colorDnicos"></i></a>
    </td></td>
      </tr>
    {% empty %}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="8" class="text-center colorVacio">No existen ventas</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
  <span class="current">
        Pagina <span class="colorDnicos">{{ ventas.number }}</span> de
        <span class="colorDnicos">{{ ventas.paginator.num_pages }}</span>.
    </span>
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        {% if ventas.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">&laquo; Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ ventas.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in ventas.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if ventas.number == i %}
            <li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
          {% else %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if ventas.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ ventas.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ ventas.paginator.num_pages }}">Ultimo &raquo;</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
  <div class="row justify-content-center spaceIndicador">
      <div class="card border-info mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Total de ventas</div>
        <div class="card-body text-info">
          <p class="card-text">EL monto es de: S/.<span class="totalVentas font-weight-bold"></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#id_min_date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            locale: 'pe'
        });
        $('#id_max_date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            locale: 'pe'
        });
        //Calculo de totales
          var sum = 0;
          $(".total-list").each(function(){
          sum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',', '.'));
        });
        $('.totalVentas').text(sum.toFixed(2));
      });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado (:
Por si alguien alguna vez necesita algo parecido aquí la solución:
simplemente en mi función le agregue al filter:

```
suma_total = venta_filter.qs.aggregate(Sum('total'))
```

y obviamente con otra variable para poder enviarle por los argumentos al template:

```
return render(request, 'venta/venta_filter.html', {'filter': venta_filter,'ventas': ventas, 'total': suma_total})
```

y en el template podemos acceder al total que siempre pone el nombre con el que estas enviando con los argumentos y agregando __sum:

```
{{total.total__sum}}
```

y quedando como:

```
def filterVenta(request):
    venta_list = Venta.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    venta_filter = VentasFilter(request.GET, queryset=venta_list)
    suma_total = venta_filter.qs.aggregate(Sum('total'))
    venta_list = venta_filter.qs
    paginator = Paginator(venta_list,10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        ventas = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        ventas = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        ventas = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'venta/venta_filter.html', {'filter': venta_filter,'ventas': ventas, 'total': suma_total})
```

Espero les sirva a alguien (:

**Actualización**
me paso que si lo paginaba pero cuando pasaba a la página 2 quitaba el filtro y me arrojaba de nuevo los datos sin el filtro entonces lo solucione de la siguiente forma en el template:

```
<span class="current">Pagina <span class="colorDnicos">{{ ventas.number }}</span> de<span class="colorDnicos">{{ ventas.paginator.num_pages }}</span>.</span>
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        {% if ventas.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">&laquo; Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ ventas.previous_page_number }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">Previous</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in ventas.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if ventas.number == i %}
            <li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
          {% else %}
            {% if forloop.counter <= 5 %}
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{forloop.counter}}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">{{forloop.counter}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if ventas.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ ventas.next_page_number }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">Next</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ ventas.paginator.num_pages }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">Ultimo &raquo;</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
```